# How to kill a process using service in Linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I'm writting a script to use service commands to add my own c++ test program into system services. Here is my script in **/etc/init.d/**:

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
    start)
        echo "Start"
        cd /home/pi/Desktop/ 
        ./main 
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Stop"
        kill $(ps aux | grep 'main' | awk '{print $2}')
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: service test start|stop"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

when I tested it with `sudo service test stop`, it could not stop the main process.
I don’t know if I made a mistake using the `kill` command.

Comment: Consider writing a [systemd unit](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/systemd.md) instead a legacy init.d script.

Comment: do you nanage to kill it manually? maybe you may consider using killall? prefere pidof to grep with ps as you may catch the pid of grep instead of the process you want

Comment: @larsks thanks! this is obviously a better way to do so